# Add word count on rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing an rmd file and I want to see the total word count at the beginning of the knitted file.

Approaches: I have seen some questions on SO but all of them are suggesting to write down a function and pass an rmd file through that function to get word count externally. But I need to add this word count in the knitted file.

Is it possible? Ant type of suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you knitting to PDF, HTML, or something else?

Comment: I'm knitting to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [`wordcountaddin`](https://github.com/benmarwick/wordcountaddin) offers the functionality you're after. Unfortunately, despite successful (?) installation, `wordcountaddin::word_count` throws an error for me so I can't test this any further.

While I am trying to get to the bottom of this, here is an alternative using no additional R packages:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

Word count: `r as.integer(sub("(\\d+).+$", "\\1", system(sprintf("wc -w %s", knitr::current_input()), intern = TRUE))) - 20`

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

This produces

[image]

The idea is to use `wc -w` to count the words in the Rmarkdown file that you are knitting. The command `system("wc -l <file>", intern = TRUE)` returns the number of words followed by the name of `<file>`; we then extract the digit part, convert to `integer` and subtract the number of words that we want to *exclude* (for example, the "words" that make up the whole `r as.integer(...)` call, the title etc. **This requires some manual adjustments and is not very elegant but works**. In this case, I played around with different values until word count gave me the number of words of the first "Lorem ipsum" paragraph.

I've tested this on both Windows 10 and MacOS and it seems to work.

Comment: I still get the following error saying "wc not found".

I installed the package from the github repo.